# Json data syntax error while fetching some column data | Snowflake

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

While working with json data found one below column contains scope resolution operator in its column name
Column name: "system::embeddable_last_seen"

how to access above column? when i was using below query to access it was throwing error **"SQL compilation error: Unsupported data type 'EMBEDDABLE_LAST_SEEN'."**
select list.value:user.system::embeddable_last_seen :: string as embeddable_last_seen

i tried using "" to use in snowflake

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select list.value:user.system:embeddable_last_seen::string
```

`::` is used for casting or type conversion in Snowflake.

When accessing the elements of a JSON use `:` only

You can go through this tutorial to better understand about parsing JSON in Snowflake. https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/json-basics-tutorial